# PostgreSQL FDW on S3 object storage

Tags: postgresql, amazon-s3, postgres-fdw

I am having one requirement for SQL-like interface to query S3 object storage(It's not actually AWS S3, but S3 based protocol storage. We are having server name, bucket name, access_key and secret_access_key available with us).

I need to know whether there exists any PostgreSQL extension which can leverage foreign data wrapper(FDW) feature to run query against S3 data.

Here, we don't want to copy the data(csv files) from S3 to postgreSQL server. We have external PostgreSQL server, using any extension, we directly want to query that S3 data using that PostgreSQL engine and get the result on PostgreSQL server.

A very similar requirement link was found as below:
https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/amazons3-jdbc-postgresql-fdw.rst

But it is using it's own cdata JDBC driver. We don't want anything proprietary.
Is there anything opensource available? If yes, how can we achieve that?

We are using 12.2 PostgreSQL version.

Comment: I found [this](https://pgxn.org/dist/s3_fdw/) [here](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Foreign_data_wrappers) but it's fairly old and doesn't mention a license. "github postgres s3 fdw" search returns a fair lot of results, [this one](https://github.com/eligoenergy/s3csv_fdw) being an example, under GNU GPL.